# Pegar valor de propriedade html via jquery

Tags: jquery

Como faço para pegar os valores das propriedades `data-pedido` e `data-id` com jquery?

```html
<h5 class="titulo-resumo pedido" data-pedido="v583161rhp" data-id="01">Pedido</h5>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a api [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/). Esta api do JQuery seleciona o valor de qualquer atributo `data-*` dentro, neste caso, de um `h5`.

```js
console.log($( "h5" ).data( "pedido" ));
console.log($( "h5" ).data( "id" ));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="titulo-resumo pedido" data-pedido="v583161rhp" data-id="01">Pedido</h5>
```